# submit action doesnt work in Rails 4

Tags: ruby, html, ruby-on-rails-4, web

when I submitted the form, the new data don't save in database and as a result I can not see them, but when I make a new data like welcome= Welcome.new and welcome.title="your are" by rails console they work and I can only see things that I have made in console not by application. It seems submit bottom doesnt save any data.

new.html.erb

```
    <h1> Submite </h1>

  <form action="new" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role ="form">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for"kind"> kind </label>
      <input type="string" id="kind" name="kind" class="form-control">
  </div>

    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for"title"> title </label>
      <input type="string" id="title" name="title" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for"text">"text </label>
      <input type="text" id="text" name="text" class="form-control">
      <br>
  </div>
      <br>
  </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
  <a href="/welcomes/index">List </a>
  </div>
```

index.html.erb

```
        <% @welcomes.each do |welcome| %>
            <li><%= welcome.title %>  </li>
          <% end %>
```

welcomes_controller

```
    def index
    @welcomes = Welcome.all
    end

    def new
         @welcome = Welcome.new
    end

    def create
         @welcome = Welcome.new(user_params)    
        if @welcome.save
         flash.keep[:notice]="Successfuly created"
               render :index
        else
        render :new
        #  format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end

       end

    private

     def user_params
        params.require(:welcome).permit(:kind, :title, :text)
      end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is not submitting to the right route. Use form builder instead:

```
<%= form_for @welcome do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :kind %>
   <%= f.text_field :kind %>

   <%= f.submit  %>
<% end %>
```

This will put right route for form submission into your HTML